# Function keys replacement for vim in a mac?

Tags: vim, macvim

I would like to know which keys (or keystrokes) would you use to replace the function keys for command mapping. I'm using vim in a macbook pro and the function keys are used for some system/desktop/multimedia commands as the first option while the regular function key is accessed through the <kbd>Fn</kbd> modifier. Still, some of the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>FX</kbd> keys are already destined for other system functions so forget about them.

Here comes my mappings:

- <kbd>F1</kbd> (default: vim help)
- <kbd>F2</kbd> -
- <kbd>F3</kbd> `:make<CR>`
- <kbd>F4</kbd> `:make run<CR>`
- <kbd>F5</kbd> `:make clean<CR>`
- <kbd>F6</kbd> `:make ctags<CR>` (generates tags file)
- <kbd>F7</kbd> `:cp<CR>` (quickfix: display previous error)
- <kbd>F8</kbd> `:cn<CR>` (quickfix: display next error)
- <kbd>F9</kbd> `:NERDTreeToggle<CR>` (filesystem explorer)
- <kbd>F10</kbd> `:TagbarToggle<CR>` (browse source code tags)
- <kbd>F11</kbd> -
- <kbd>F12</kbd> -

The commands I am missing the most are those of <kbd>F9</kbd> and <kbd>F10</kbd>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim's help has a [topic](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#map-which-keys) about this.

I generally opt for the last suggestion and use [<Leader>](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3CLeader%3E) as the prefix for my mappings since I know it doesn't conflict with any default keybindings and it can easily be changed if I decide I don't want to use `\`.

Comment: As I have commented on the other answer, I was expecting that one comes and tell he/she uses `<leader>[a-l]` (consider that as the middle row at the keyboard). I have temporarily mapped `\a` for 'NERDTreeToggle' and `\f` for 'Tagbar'

Answer (score 1):

You can map any key (or key sequerce) you want to `f9` or `f10`. Put something like this in your .vimrc:

```
:noremap gm <F9>
```

or maybe:

```
:noremap gm :NERDTreeToggle<Return>
```

If you map it to something you can use in insert mode too, I think you have to make a separate mapping for that:

```
:noremap <C-T> :NERDTreeToggle<Return>
:inoramap <C-T> <ESC>:NERDTreeToggle<Return>
:vnoramap <C-T> <ESC>:NERDTreeToggle<Return>
```

You can probably just map to `<F9>`, but I put it in the long way because I don't have the F9 mapping.

Comment: `:noremap gm <F9>`: this will map `gm` to `<F9>` which is already mapped to `sbrubbles` so `gm` will be mapped to `sbrubbles`? Is it right?

Comment: ahh thanks.. the vim docs are not very clear about that command. Although, I would like to know more about the replacing keys and less about how to map them.

Comment: for instance, one could tell me to use `,tag` to toggle the tagbar window. I'm just looking for some ideas, maybe someone comes with a bunch of keystrokes I haven't thought about that are just as easy as the function keys.

Comment: @freitass: Use whichever mappings make sense to you and are easy for you to remember.